# How to pass Java options to Puma daemon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, jruby, supervisord, puma

I have a Rails application running on `jruby-9.0.4.0` and using Puma as the web server.

I am trying to increase the memory limit of `puma`; the current flags are `-Xmx500m -Xss2048k`. I added `_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xss4096k -Xmx2048m` to my `env` and all the `jruby` processes use it like `rake assets:precompile` for example but the `puma` instance itself does not.

**Part of capistrano trace**

```
DEBUG [0aec947c] Command: cd 
/dummy/production/releases/20160707071111 && ( 
export RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="jruby-9.0.4.0" 
RAILS_ENV="production" ; /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec 
rake assets:precompile )

DEBUG [0aec947c]    Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xss4096k -Xmx2048m
```

**config/puma.rb**

```
# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 8, 512

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'
environment rails_env

app_dir = "/dummy/#{rails_env}/current"

# Set up socket location
bind "tcp://localhost:3000"

# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{app_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{app_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "#{app_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{app_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app
```

**ENV variables**

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xss4096k -Xmx2048m
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xss4096k -Xmx2048m
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64
```

**Output of `cat /proc/<pid>/environ`**

> RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenvprevious=NUPSTART_JOB=rcPATH=/dummy/production/shared/bundle/jruby/2.2.0/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-9.0.4.0/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/libexec:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/binPWD=/dummy/production/releases/20160707133222RBENV_DIR=/dummy/production/releases/20160707133222SUPERVISOR_SERVER_URL=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sockUPSTART_EVENTS=runlevelRUNLEVEL=2NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.catSUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME=dummyprocessSUPERVISOR_ENABLED=1XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/DtSHLVL=0UPSTART_INSTANCE=PREVLEVEL=NRBENV_VERSION=jruby-9.0.4.0RBENV_HOOK_PATH=:/usr/local/rbenv/rbenv.d:/usr/local/etc/rbenv.d:/etc/rbenv.d:/usr/lib/rbenv/hooksrunlevel=2SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME=dummyprocessTERM=linuxRUBYOPT=-rbundler/setupRUBYLIB=/usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-9.0.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.11.2/libroot

Machine is an 8-core with 24GB of RAM.

How can I let the `puma` instance also pick up the `Java` options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@richardsondx/everything-you-should-know-about-the-obscure-world-of-jruby-jruby-with-ruby-on-rails-c3c90d8fdeec#bc1b), you can put the JVM options in `JRUBY_OPTS` environment variable.

In your case, you could set the variable before starting Puma daemon :

```
export JRUBY_OPTS="-J-Xss4096k -J-Xmx2048m"
```

You may also try configuring the JVM directly by setting `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable :

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xss4096k -Xmx2048m"
```

Also check how the `puma` daemon is started

```
cat /proc/<pid>/environ
```

Your environment is not propagated to the Puma daemon. You need to find out how Puma is started. It may be as an [init.d service](https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/init.d) or an [upstart service](https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/upstart).

**Update:**

It seems you can set your environment with [rbenv-vars](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-vars).

Create a `.rbenv-vars` file in your Rails project with the following

```
JAVA_OPTS='-Xss4096k -Xmx2048m'
```

Then your environment should be propagated to the `puma` daemon.

Comment: I already have these variables in my environment, the Puma daemon does not seem to pick them up. It launches with its own flags thus it ignores all other variables. I will update the question to add my env. Thanks though.

Comment: How the Puma daemon is started? What is the actual environment of the Puma process? You can print it by running `cat /proc/<pid>/environ`, where `<pid>` is the process id of the Puma daemon.

Comment: Added it to the question since it is too long for a comment.

Comment: Ok, so your environment is not propagated to the Puma daemon. You need to find out how Puma is started. It may be as an [init.d service](https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/init.d) or an [upstart  service](https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/upstart).

Comment: Also, it seems you can set your environment with [rbenv-vars](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-vars).

Comment: Went from upstart to supervisord and then rbenv-vars solved the issue! Thanks! I updated the answer witht he comments. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/optimizing-dyno-usage#basic-methodology-for-optimizing-memory

> JRuby
>
> JRuby servers like Puma make good use of concurrency without the need
>   for multiple processes. However, you will need to tune the amount of
>   memory allocated to the JVM, depending on the dyno type. The Ruby
>   buildpack defines sensible defaults, which can be overridden by
>   setting either JAVA_OPTS or JRUBY_OPTS.

Comment: Yes `_JAVA_OPTIONS` should be used by all running `java` processes. `JAVA_OPTS` should be specified in the args though. The first is captured by all `rake` tasks that run while deployment but not by the `puma` daemon.